# GUI wont run even though program compiles

Tags: java, user-interface

Im new to programming and was asked to create a GUI that reads in a name of a text file from a textfield and display in the textarea. This is what ive completed so far.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;


public class FileLoader extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


private final LayoutManager layout;
private JButton loadButton;
private JTextField filename;
private JTextArea display;

public FileLoader() 
{

layout = new FlowLayout();
  setLayout(layout);
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

   loadButton = new JButton("Load File");
   filename = new JTextField(10);
   buttonPanel.add(filename);
   buttonPanel.add(loadButton);
   display = new JTextArea(25, 50);

   add(new JLabel("File Name: "));
   add(filename);
   add(new JScrollPane(display));
   add(loadButton);



   loadButton.addActionListener(this);


 }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
 try{

   String file = filename.getText();
   int filesize = file.length();

if (filesize>= 5 && filesize<= 10){
  Scanner input = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file));
  String DisTXT = " ";
  while (input.hasNextLine()){
   DisTXT = DisTXT  + input.nextLine();
  if (input.hasNextLine()){
      DisTXT = DisTXT  + "\n";
}
}
 display.setText(DisTXT);
input.close();
}
else
{
if (filesize< 5){
 display.setText("File NAME ERROR: NAME IS TOO SHORT");
} 
else {
display.setText("File NAME ERROR: NAME IS TOO LONG"); 
} 

 }  
}
catch (NullPointerException e) { 
display.setText("File not found");
}
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new FileLoader();

 }
 }
```

after checking it multilple times, the logic in the code makes sense (to me atleast, please let me know if you catch something i mightve missed) the only issue is for some reason when i go to run it, nothing happens. Im sorry if there is a simple solution to this question, but we are only on day 2 of GUIs, and im not quite sure why this is the case, can someone please explain?

Comment: You never show the frame

Comment: Where do you call `.setVisible(true)` on the JFrame? No place, so nothing shows.

Comment: The question suggests that you will want to check out the official Swing tutorials. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Comment: This, `catch (NullPointerException e) {`, should *never* be in your code. Check for null before an exception gets thrown.

Comment: You're missing quite a few things. The constructor should have at the end of it: `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack(); 
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);`

Comment: I would also recommend that rather than have the user type in a file name, use a JFileChooser which is more "idiot-proof".